# Can I display a log of not every epoch when training a neural network?

Tags: keras, neural-network

When training a neural network, each epoch is logged. How can I output only every 100th or every 1000th epoch?

```
history = model.fit(train_enc_X, 
                    train_enc_y, 
                    epochs=10000, 
                    validation_split=0.2, 
                    batch_size = train_enc_X.shape[0],
                    callbacks=[early_stop],
                    verbose=1)
```

The verbose parameter changes the details of each record, but not their number.

The program outputs:

```
Epoch 1/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 282ms/step - loss: 5051431.5000 - mae: 1036.0717 - val_loss: 2393038336.0000 - val_mae: 23748.4395
Epoch 2/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 244ms/step - loss: 5046309.0000 - mae: 1035.4728 - val_loss: 2392878080.0000 - val_mae: 23748.3535
Epoch 3/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 240ms/step - loss: 5041162.0000 - mae: 1034.8594 - val_loss: 2392722432.0000 - val_mae: 23748.2656
```

e t.c.

I want:

```
Epoch 1/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 282ms/step - loss: 5051431.5000 - mae: 1036.0717 - val_loss: 2393038336.0000 - val_mae: 23748.4395
Epoch 10/10000
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 286ms/step - loss: 5005304.5000 - mae: 1030.5120 - val_loss: 2391655168.0000 - val_mae: 23748.1465
```

e t c